# docker-py : PermissionError(13)

Tags: python, linux, docker, dockerpy

While I was running

```py
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> client.containers.list()
```

I encountered the following error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

I think it is because docker-py is not able to get access of the docker daemon. So how do I fix this?

Comment: You add your user to the group set up to run docker? On [arch linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/docker#Installation) that would be the `docker` group.

Comment: You'll have to log back in to pick up the group addition, most likely

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) you should create a group and attach your user to that group.

Create Group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Attach User to Group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Reload

```
su -s ${USER}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a running docker service?  You may need to start it first:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

or whatever the equivalent is on your system.

Or if you're on RHEL8 and using podman, you can do something like:

```
podman system service tcp:localhost:8080 --time=0 &
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it just needed `sudo` permission -
I installed `docker` package like this -

```bash
sudo pip3 install docker
```

Then by running the python script with sudo removed the issue -

```
sudo python3 docker-wrapper.py
```

Hope this helps someone.